# Struggling with PHP strategy pattern and interface inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, strategy-pattern

Laravel 5.4 PHP app here.

I need strategies to use diferent algorythms to enroll students in a school depending from where the data comes from.

There is two endpoints for the 2 data providers.

This are normal routes that hit controller methods.

```php
<?php

class WebhookController 
{
    public function endpointDataProvider1(FormRequestData1 $request)
    {
        // some particular logic
        $this->enrollmentService->enroll($request)
    }

    public function endpointDataProvider2(FormRequestData2 $request) 
    {
        // some particular logic
        $this->enrollmentService->enroll($request)
    }
}
```

This methods inject 2 different form request since the data maybe different depending the provider.

```php
<?php

class FormRequestData1 implements Data1
{
    public function rules() 
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function getFirstName() {}
    public function getLastName() {}
    public function getProvider() {}
    public function getSomeParticularRandomData() {}

}

class FormRequestData2 implements Data2
{
    public function rules() 
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getFirstName() {}
    public function getLastName() {}
    public function getProvider() {}
    public function getOtherParticularRandomData() {}
}
```

This form requests implements interfaces with different getters depending the data provider.

```php
<?php

interface Data
{
    public function getFirstName();
    public function getLastName();
    public function getProvider();
}

interface Data1 extends Data
{
    public function getSomeParticularRandomData();
}


interface Data2 extends Data
{
    public function getOtherParticularRandomData();

}
```

The controller methods call an EnrollmentService which decides through a factory which strategy to use depending of which data provider is making the call.

```php
<?php

class EnrollmentService
{
    public function enroll(Data $data) 
    {
        $strategy = $this->enrollmentStrategyFactory->make($data->getProvider());
        $strategy->enroll($data);
    }
}
```

And the strategies:

```php
<?php
abstract class EnrollmentStrategy
{
    public abstract function enroll(Data $data);
}
class Provider1EnrollmentStrategy extends EnrollmentStrategy 
{
    public abstract function enroll(Data1 $data);
}
class Provider2EnrollmentStrategy extends EnrollmentStrategy 
{
    public abstract function enroll(Data2 $data);
}
```

My problem is that here I should get an error. Because even if interfaces `Data1` and `Data2` extends interface `Data`, the child strategies are implementing `Data1` and `Data2` and its parent strategy is implementing the parent interface `Data`;

If I type hint `Data` everywhere I loose consistency because I should be sure to have available  `getSomeParticularRandomData` and `getOtherParticularRandomData` methods wherever it correspond.

It's more like a design question.

Any sort of advice welcome, i hope i didn't too much of a mess with the examples.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you saying that you *are* getting an error with this design pattern? Or that you're *expecting* one and it's not happening?

Comment: No, i'm getting the error, and phpstorm is red underlining it

Comment: I'm not sure about having well understood your issue, but what about only 1 interface, 2 classes implementing it (so exactly same methods) and use contextual binding thanks to Laravel's container to get your strategy pattern?

Comment: @Shizzen83 The data from the different providers is different, thats why I need different methods in the interfaces.
Interfaces here are playing another role, just providing getters for the incoming data to the form requests and providing consistency. 
About the strategy parent i used an abstract class instead of an interface, which i believe is alright.  

I understand about contextual binding, but i just created a factory to choose my strategy.